# Splitting Values into 12 Consecutive Months Evenly (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to evenly distribute values into the next consecutive 12 months.  Below is what I currently have and following that is what I am trying to achieve. If someone can please help out with this would appreciate it. Thank you!

[image]

```
Type    Year    January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
Saving  2019    $1,740,000   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
REBATE  2018     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  $1,640,000   -   -   - 
REBATE  2019     -   -   -  $12,869      -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

============================================================

```
Request_Name    Type    Year    January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
Microsoft   Saving  2019    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000    $145,000 
Apple   REBATE  2018     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  $136,667    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667 
Apple   REBATE  2019    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667    $136,667         -   -   - 
Sony    REBATE  2019     -   -   -  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072  $1,072 
Sony    REBATE  2020    $1,072  $1,072  $1,072   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

this is the code I currently have -

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS ******/
SELECT * 
FROM (
      SELECT TASK_ID,
              datename(month, [START_DATE]) 'Month', 
             [INITIATIVE_TYPE],
             DATEpart(year, [START_DATE]) 'Year',
             sum([TOTAL_SAVINGS]) TotalSavings 
       FROM [PRIME].[dbo].[SAV_FORM_DATA] 
       GROUP BY 
                TASK_ID,
                CATEGORY ,
                [INITIATIVE_TYPE],
                [START_DATE] 
       ) tbl 
PIVOT
   (SUM(totalsavings) 
    FOR [Month] IN ( [January] ,[February] ,[March] ,[April] ,
                     [May] ,[June] ,[July] ,[August] ,[September],
                     [October] ,[November] ,[December])) M
```

Comment: Try to fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Please add table structures and some sample data and expected results. Format your code using the {} button as per my edit.

Comment: hi Steve Thank you for the reply, I have uploaded the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a recursive query to iteratively add a month to current date through the next year. Then with each month row divide total savings by 12.

Below is an untested SQL adjustment, requiring your further refinement. However, see [Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/BWQ86599) demonstrating the process works.

```
WITH agg AS (
   SELECT TASK_ID,
          [INITIATIVE_TYPE],
          [START_DATE],
          SUM([TOTAL_SAVINGS]) AS TotalSavings 
   FROM [PRIME].[dbo].[SAV_FORM_DATA] 
   GROUP BY 
          TASK_ID,
          [INITIATIVE_TYPE],
          [START_DATE]
),

dates AS (   
   SELECT agg.TASK_ID, 
          agg.[INITIATIVE_TYPE],
          agg.[START_DATE] AS rec_date, 
          agg.TotalSavings / 12 as TotalMonthSavings
   FROM agg
   UNION ALL
   SELECT agg.mytype, 
          agg.[INITIATIVE_TYPE],
          DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rec_date), 
          agg.TotalSavings / 12
   FROM dates
   INNER JOIN agg
     ON agg.TASK_ID = dates.TASK_ID
     AND agg.[INITIATIVE_TYPE] = dates.[INITIATIVE_TYPE] 
     AND dates.rec_date <  DATEADD(MONTH, 11, agg.[START_DATE])
)


SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT TASK_ID, 
         [INITIATIVE_TYPE],
         DATEPART(YEAR, rec_date) AS [Year],
         DATENAME(MONTH, rec_date) AS [Month], 
         TotalMonthSavings
  FROM dates
  ) tbl

PIVOT
   (SUM(TotalMonthSavings) 
    FOR [Month] IN ([January], [February], [March], [April],
                    [May], [June], [July], [August], [September],
                    [October], [November], [December])
   ) M
ORDER BY TASK_ID, 
         [INITIATIVE_TYPE], 
         [Year]
```

Comment: Thank you, was excatly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you need to create 11 additional rows for each entry, incremented by between 1 and 11 months from the starting date.

In a simple case like this, it might be easier to just calculate 1/12th of the value, then cross join with a hard-coded numbers table consisting of entries 0 to 11 (which can be written as a one-liner in SQL Server), calculate the final date by DATEADDing the relevant number of months to the initial date, and you'll now have rows with the relevant dates and values, ready for pivoting into the final form.

Use one-liner cross-apply clauses for the calculated columns.